# What's supposed to happen when you set up a realtime subscription to "likes"

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, real-time

I'd like to be notified when my site's users "like" something.  This is supposed to be possible according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/, and I've in fact been able to set up my app so that it's subscribed to "likes".

The question is, now what happens?  If my user clicks on a "like" button, my app does get an update at the usual callback.  The problem is that it's a "feed" update to the user object, which just means that the user's feed has changed in some way, and it's up to you to figure out how.  I guess I was expecting that I'd get a "like" update to the user object, but that's not what I'm getting. Any insights out there?

Comment: i'd suggest you just post the questions here -- I know a bit about the API, but there are surely others who hang out here and who know a lot more!